# UIWebview load request fails if URL has a fragment identifier (#)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My app displays information which uses specialised keywords. When the user touches one of these keywords, the app opens a UIWebView that gives additional information about the keyword. Here is the code that creates the UIWebview:

```
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: currentURL] ;
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
[webView setDelegate: self];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Everything works fine for a simple URL "chapter5.html" but if the URL has a fragment identifier "chapter5.html#section3", the page does not open at all- not even at the start of chapter5.

I'm guessing that it's trying to use the whole thing as a filename and failing because no such file exists. If I strip off the fragment identifier, the page is displayed, but not at the right place. Is there a way of either

- getting the loadRequest to honour the fragment identifier, or
- doing the loadRequest without the fragment identifier, then subsequently adjusting the position to that of the fragment identifier?

Answer (score 0):

You have to split off the fragment identifier (hashTag) then give the rest of the URL to UIWebview. You can do it like this:

```
NSRange range = [url rangeOfString: @"#"];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    hashTag = nil;
}
else {
    hashTag = [url substringFromIndex: range.location];
    url = [url substringToIndex:range.location];
}
```

Then you set up your viewController as a UIWebViewDelegate and wait to be told that the page has been loaded. Once it's loaded, you can then use a javascript command to go to the location specified by the hashTag:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) localWebView {

    if (hashTag != nil) {
        NSString * javaScript = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"window.location.hash = '%@'", hashTag];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
        hashTag = nil;
    }

}
```